# Retrieve postgres column types from psycopg2 cursor (or more efficienly map postgres oids to types)

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

So I'm writing a script that runs a bunch of different postgres sql queries stored in files, and writes the results (with some additional calcuations) back to an output table.  Since queries can be added or changed to include more columns, the script will attempt to alter the output table to include corresponding new columns.

I know that I can retrieve the postgres oids for the columns in a query using the cursor description, and then run a query to postgres to convert the oid into a string form of the postgres data type:

```
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
coloids = [desc[1] for desc in cur.description]
coltypes = [get_pg_type_from_oid(x) for x in coloids]
...
oid_catalog = {
    20:  'BIGINT',
    23 : 'INTEGER',
    1043: 'TEXT',
    1700: 'REAL',
}
def get_pg_type_from_oid(oid):
    if oid in oid_catalog:
        log.debug("converting oid type {} into {}".format(oid, oid_catalog[oid]))
        return oid_catalog[oid]
    q = "select {}::oid::regtype".format(oid)
    with conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(q)
        newtype = cur.fetchone()[0]
        log.debug("converting oid type {} into {}".format(oid, newtype))
        oid_catalog[oid] = newtype
        return newtype
```

However, the data type strings returned by my get_pg_type_from_oid seem to be in a different format than those I'd typically use for creating a new table or adding columns (e.g., "character varying" instead of "VARCHAR(X)" and so on).

Is there an easier way to get this mapping?  I've started just manually hardcoding specific mappings to the stored oid_catalog where I need to, but I'd love a more general and elegant solution.

Relatedly, is there any way to make results fetched from cursor.fetchall() represent themselves, as a string, with the necessary formatting for direct inclusion into a query?

I'm currently doing this manually (see code below) but my intuition is that there must be a better way.

```
def stringify(l):
    newl = []
    for x in l:
        if isinstance(x,float) or isinstance(x,Decimal):
            newl.append("{0:.2f}".format(round(float(x),2)))
        elif isinstance(x, datetime.datetime):
            newl.append("(TIMESTAMP '{}')".format(x.isoformat()))
        elif isinstance(x, datetime.date):
            newl.append("'{}'".format(str(x)))
        elif type(x) is str:
            newl.append("'"+x+"'")
        else:  # type(x) == 'int':
            #log.info("type else used for {}".format(x))
            newl.append(str(x))
    #log.debug("new string = {}".format(newl))
    return list(newl)
```

Answer (score 0):

- `character varying` is a perfectly valid type:

```
$ psql

=# select pg_typeof(''::varchar);
     pg_typeof     
-------------------
 character varying

=# select 1::character varying(10);
 varchar 
---------
 1
```

however you can get other names (which might be the canonical one) from the `pg_type` table, using the `oid` hidden field.

```
=# select pg_typeof(''::varchar)::oid;
 pg_typeof 
-----------
      1043

=# select typname from pg_type where oid = pg_typeof(''::varchar)::oid;
 typname 
---------
 varchar
```

- you can customize the adapter used by psycog to represent your data: check the docs for [adapting Python types to SQL syntax](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-python-types-to-sql-syntax)